# Why does the Apple Watch health reminders pop up at 50 minutes past the hour?

Tags: reminders, apple-watch, health.app

The Apple Watch gives me health reminders about standing or walking goals. These reminders pop up at 10 to the hour - ie at XX:50.

This seems like an opinionated choice, but I thought there might be something behind it, some reasoning I'm missing.

My question is: **Why does the Apple Watch health reminders pop up at 50 minutes past the hour?**

Comment: Asking why Apple does X is generally off topic. The reason is that it revolves around a) waiting for Apple to document why they implemented something b) speculation c) opinion. If there is something you are trying to do that relates to Apple's choice, that works better for a Q/A site where answers can be objectively voted and accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple Watch wants you to stand each hour to complete your stand goal. So if you haven't stood during all the hour, it will remind you to do it 10 minutes before the next hour to give the the time to stand a little and add an hour to your stand goal !

It's anyway what apple says on [their website](https://www.apple.com/watch/health-and-fitness/) :

> Even if you’re active part of the day, sitting too long has its own health risks. So Apple Watch senses when you stand and move just a bit and gives you credit. And if you’ve been sitting for almost an hour, it reminds you to get up. You close the Stand ring when you’ve stood and moved for at least one minute in 12 different hours during the day. It may sound like a small thing, but sitting less can improve your health in significant ways.